# Unable to send email in iOS app IN Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, send, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

```
- (IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController* composeVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        // Configure the fields of the interface.
        [composeVC setToRecipients:@[@"address@example.com"]];
        [composeVC setSubject:@"Hello!"];
        [composeVC setMessageBody:@"Hello from California!" isHTML:NO];

        // Present the view controller modally.
        [self presentViewController:composeVC animated:YES completion:nil];
      // composeVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet ;
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                        message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

It always goes in the `else` condition even when tested on real device. please help. this works in other Xcode versions

Comment: Does the device have at least one working email account setup?

Comment: Did you add `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` in `@interface`

Comment: yes i added the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate in @interface